# AWS Lambda with Serverless Annotations in .net: How to require an API Key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I started a blank serverless application project that uses AWS Lambda Annotations. It generated the following `serverless.template`:

```json
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "An AWS Serverless Application. This template is partially managed by Amazon.Lambda.Annotations (v1.0.0.0).",
  "Resources": {
    "MyAppFunctionsGetGenerated": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Metadata": {
        "Tool": "Amazon.Lambda.Annotations",
        "SyncedEvents": [
          "RootGet"
        ]
      },
      "Properties": {
        "Runtime": "dotnet6",
        "CodeUri": ".",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Policies": [
          "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
        ],
        "PackageType": "Zip",
        "Handler": "MyApp::MyApp.Functions_Get_Generated::Get",
        "Events": {
          "RootGet": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/",
              "Method": "GET"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
      "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How and where should I put the configuration stuff to require API Keys? I tried different approaches I found here on SO but they don't work, they only work for the older approach without Annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question to be able to accept it later.

Since the Annotations approach generates a lot of stuff behind the scenes which is not directly accessible, including the API, you have to rely on `Fn::Sub` to get the API Id you need to link to the usage plan.

Then, you can use the default Usage Plan, API Key, Usage Plan Key route.

Here is what I pieced together:

```json
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "An AWS Serverless Application. This template is partially managed by Amazon.Lambda.Annotations (v1.0.0.0).",
  "Resources": {
    "MyApiKey": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey",
      "Properties": {
        "Enabled": true
      }
    },
    "MyUsagePlan": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan",
      "Properties": {
        "ApiStages": [
          {
            "ApiId": { "Fn::Sub" : "${ServerlessRestApi}" },
            "Stage": "Prod"
          },
          {
            "ApiId": { "Fn::Sub" : "${ServerlessRestApi}" },
            "Stage": "Stage"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "MyUsagePlanKey": {
      "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey",
      "Properties": {
        "KeyId": {
          "Ref": "MyApiKey"
        },
        "KeyType": "API_KEY",
        "UsagePlanId": {
          "Ref": "MyUsagePlan"
        }
      }
    },
    "MyAppFunctionsGetGenerated": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Metadata": {
        "Tool": "Amazon.Lambda.Annotations",
        "SyncedEvents": [
          "RootGet"
        ]
      },
      "Properties": {
        "Runtime": "dotnet6",
        "CodeUri": ".",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Policies": [
          "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
        ],
        "PackageType": "Zip",
        "Handler": "MyApp::MyApp.Functions_Get_Generated::Get",
        "Events": {
          "RootGet": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/",
              "Method": "GET",
              "Auth": {
                "ApiKeyRequired": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
      "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```